# Assembly string modifying within Code Segment

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, serial-communication

OK, so I'm using MASM DosBox for 8086 and I have two problems here that I can't really find a solution for. I've been looking for 3 days now for a solution with no use, so please be nice and helpful.

I'm working on some project for myself, this project is about serial communication chat, where "Welcome Screen" starts with asking for your '**UserName**', and then it takes you to MainMenu ...

First Problem here that I want the Welcome Screen to wait until the other PC enters his '**UserName**' as well, so it receives it as, let's say '**PartnerName**'... I can't send the string over the Serial Comm UART-8250 serial port, I can only send immediate values or an ASCII for a key. (No, I don't want to loop the whole String, Character by Character) So how can I send the whole string as a frame ?

Second problem here is that I have a notification part down the monitor where it updates according to the user inputs, the thing is that I can't update it ... Let's say it is "TEST" by default, and when User presses F1, it should update by "*You sent a Chat Request to [**PartnerName**]*"... Let's call that string "**NotificationMsg**". So to be clear, I can't change the contents of NotificationMsg, or even add "**PartnerName**" to the end of it.

If I'm still unclear, please feel free to ask me more about what you want to know.

Thanks for your time, once again please be nice and helpful !

EDIT : THESE ARE PARTS OF MY CODE, AS REQUESTED:

This part is from a PROC called "Welcome" AKA Welcome Screen, it shouldn't return unless I receive a string in PartnerName *I know my code is wrong*

```
;Reading PlayerName
mov ah,0ah
lea dx,PlayerName
int 21h

; Adding $ at the end, so we can print it later
mov bx,00
mov bl,PlayerName[1]
mov PlayerName[bx+2],'$'



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CHECKING FOR NAME;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
SendingName:  ;Sending Player Name
mov dx,3fdh
in al,dx
test al,01000000b
jnz SendNameDone
jmp SendingName
SendNameDone:
lea ax,[PlayerName]
mov dx,3f8h 
out dx,ax


ReceivingName:  ;Receiving PLayer Name
mov dx,3fdh
in al,dx
test al,00000001b
jnz ReceiveNameDone
jmp ReceivingName   ;This will occur if nothing is received.
ReceiveNameDone:
mov dx,3f8h
in ax,dx
mov si,ax
mov di,OFFSET PartnerName
mov cx,15
movsb

mov dh,1   ;Row number
mov dl,1   ;Column number
mov bh,0
mov ah,2
int 10h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,PartnerName
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
```

This is another part of "MainMenu" Where the msgs should be updated

```
;Notification ONE
mov ah,02
mov dh,23d
mov dl,00d
int 10h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,DS:Notif1
int 21h
;Notification TWO
mov ah,02
mov dh,24d
mov dl,00d
int 10h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,DS:Notif2
int 21h

WaitKeyPrs:
mov ah,01h  ;Check for keystroke in the keyboard buffer.
int 16h
jz ReqRec   ;If zero = no key pressed. i.e. We check for Receiving.
mov ah,00h  ;Get keystroke from keyboard.
int 16h

cmp al,27d     ;Escape pressed !
jz QuitThis

SendReqID:
cmp al,3Bh     ;F1 comparing
jz F1Prs

cmp al,3Ch     ;F2 comparing
jz F2Prs

jmp WaitKeyPrs


ReqSend:        ;We send the Request here !
mov cl,al
mov dx,3fdh     ;We check if HoldReg is empty or not
in al,dx
test al,01000000b
jnz SendReqDone
jmp ReqRec
jmp ReqRec

SendReqDone:
mov al,cl
mov dx,3f8h 
out dx,al       ;By now, the Request should be sent.
jmp ReqRec


F1Prs:
mov ah,02
mov dh,23d
mov dl,00d
int 10h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,DS:ChatReqSend
int 21h
jmp ReqSend

F2Prs:
mov ah,02
mov dh,23d
mov dl,00d
int 10h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,DS:GameReqSend
int 21h
jmp ReqSend
```

In the last piece of code, Notif1 should be updated with what's in ChatReqSend or GameReqSend according to user input ... so I just need to use Only ONE string in the data segment and update it as the choice, not just use another string called ChatReqSend or GameReqSend ...

Here's a part of my Data Segment:

```
Data_segment_name segment para
Notif1 db 'TEST $'
Notif2 db 'TEST2 $'
ChatReqSend db 'You sent a Chat Request to.$'
GameReqSend db 'You sent a Game Request to.$'
ChatReqRec db 'You received a Chat Request from.$'
GameReqRec db 'You received a Game Request from.$'
ReqFlag db 00h ;0 If no request, 1 if chat, 2 if game.
PlayerName db 15,?,15 dup(?)
PartnerName db 15 dup (' ')
Data_segment_name ends
```

Comment: Without seeing the code I doubt that anyone here can help you much.

Comment: @PaulR, agreed. user3054349, show us something, anything.  Bonus points if you'll comment each line.  As for, "... *No, I don't want to loop the whole String* ..." I have a big "duh" in my brain, because that's the simplest (and honestly, the only) way I know how to do that.

Comment: Done adding what you might need, thanks for your time.

Comment: Each time you set the cursor position through BIOS you forget the BH parameter!

Answer (score 0):

```
cmp al,3Bh     ;F1 comparing
jz F1Prs
cmp al,3Ch     ;F2 comparing
jz F2Prs
```

You need to compare with AH. That's the register that has the scancode!

```
SendNameDone:
lea ax,[PlayerName]
```

I think you need the address 2 bytes higher up in memory.

```
lea dx,DS:Notif1
lea dx,DS:Notif2
lea dx,DS:ChatReqSend
```

Several times you use these constructs with DS: but did you actually initialize the DS register somewhere?

```
PlayerName db 15,?,15 dup(?)
```

This could produce a buffer overflow. You allowed DOS to input 15 characters with no room for the terminating carriage return. Better use `db 15,0,16,dup(?)`. Also note I changed the second byte to zero. It also has input meaning!

Comment: On an original DOS 6.2 specifying 15 would allow a 14 character input. Some documents however state the extra byte is necessary. So to be sure I always provide the extra byte.

Comment: Yes, I initialized the DS with my "Data_Segment_Name" don't worry.

Maybe I really have to edit the playername part like you did. But the problem here is that I don't understand why do I need the address 2 bytes higher up in memory ? and Thanks for the "Scancode" part, it really helped !

Comment: In the *ReceivingName* routine you are only interested in the actual name that was inputted. So you have to skip the first 2 bytes at *PlayerName* since they contain numerical info for DOS's bookkeeping.